# Converting DEC to BIN value in dos assembly

Tags: assembly, binary, decimal, dos, nasm

I am reading input number in decimal format using buffered input (0Ah function of interrupt 21h), like this:

```
mov ah, 0Ah
mov dx, inputBuffer
int 21h
```

I declared the buffer this way:

```
inputBuffer     db  6
                db  0
                times 7 db  "$"
```

Now I want to cycle through the numbers and make a binary representation of this value, following code does this for me:

```
mov si, [inputBuffer+1]
mov di, 0
dec si

process_input_value:
xor dx, dx
mov ax, [inputValue]
mov dx, [inputBuffer+2+di]
sub dx, '0'
add ax, dx
mov bx, 10
mul bx
mov [inputValue], ax

inc di
cmp di, si
jb process_input_value

mov ax, [inputValue]
mov dx, [inputBuffer+2+di]
sub dx, '0'
add ax, dx
mov [inputValue], ax
```

The algorithm I use goes as follows:

1. add number to buffer
2. if it's not the last number multiply buffer by 10
3. repeat

Unfortunately, when I later print out this value I always get the same output, no matter what I type in the beginning. The code that shows output (it just shows one ASCII character for each byte, but it's enough for me to notice the error):

```
mov ah, 2
mov dl, 10
int 21h
mov dx, [inputValue]
mov dl, dh
int 21h
mov dx, [inputValue]
int 21h
mov ah, 8
int 21h
```

It feels like there is a problem with the code which does the converting, but I have no idea what could be wrong.

I am using NASM.

EDIT:
Answer from Guffa was just the solution I needed, it works perfectly now, thank you very much.

Comment: xor dx, dx  - what's the purpose of clearing DX if you read from memory into DX two instruction later?

Comment: mov ax, [inputValue] - you read ASCIIs 16 bit wise? are they stored as 16 bit items in buffer too? or is your intention to read them 8 bit wise, in which case you may want to load into AL instead?

Comment: @Bushmills inputValue is a word used to hold binary value of input number. That's why it's mov ax, [inputValue].

Also, to your first question: I am moving the amount of 8bit numbers I entered at the beginning.

Comment: oh, right. "Value" vs "Buffer" - as both start with "input", that detail slipped my attention

Comment: Question should have been about mov dx, [inputBuffer+2+di], not about mov ax, [inputValue], where that's done too

Comment: Also, logic seems wrong when you add numeric value of digit to accumulator, and then multiply accumulator with 10. Should be other way around:  Multiply accumulator with 10, then add numeric value.

Comment: Well, use a debugger which allows you to single step through your code, and displays registers and specified memory contents while doing so - that way you see where things go awry the moment they are done.

Comment: @Bushmills: The logic isn't exactly wrong, it works as there is additional code that adds the last digit without multiplying. However, with that logic it should not enter the loop if the input is a single digit. The logic that you suggest makes for a lot simpler code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this code you are getting two characters into `dx`:

```
mov dx, [inputBuffer+2+di]
```

You should be getting one character:

```
xor dx, dx
mov dl, [inputBuffer+2+di]
```

(The clearing of `dx` first is so that you get a full 16 bit value so that you can easily add it to `ax` later.)

#### Edit:

The same when you are getting the length:

```
xor ax, ax
mov al, [inputBuffer+1]
mov si, ax
```

#### Edit 2:

Also, as Bushmills points out, the logic that you are using to convert the value is a bit backwards. If you multiply the accumulator and then add the digit, you don't need additional code to handle the last digit, and you don't need a check to skip the loop if the input is a single digit (which was lacking in the code).

With that logic the code would be:

```
xor ax, ax
mov di, ax
mov al, [inputBuffer+1]
mov si, ax
dec si

xor ax, ax
process_input_value:
mov bx, 10
mul bx
xor dx, dx
mov dl, [inputBuffer+2+di]
sub dl, '0'
add ax, dx
inc di
cmp di, si
jb process_input_value
mov [inputValue], ax
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to make a difference, the output is still the same (ASCII code 170 and 176).

Comment: @Tomek: Just noticed that you also read the length as a word. I added the code above.